# escaping special character in a url

Tags: javascript, url, special-characters

I am using a url to open a html page, and i am sending data in querystring withe the page url.

For example: `abc.html?firstParameter=firstvalue&seconedParameter=seconedvalue`

Problem is that if `firstvalue` or `secondvalue` in parameter contains 
special character like `#,(,),%,{`, then my url is not constructing well. In this case url is not validating.
I am doing all this in `javascript`. 
Can any body please help me out this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have 3 options:

```
escape() will not encode: @*/+

encodeURI() will not encode: ~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'

encodeURIComponent() will not encode: ~!*()'
```

But in your case, if you want to pass a url into a GET parameter of other page, you should use escape or encodeURIComponent, but not encodeURI.

Comment: thanx yogesh, please can you tell me how to use these methods in javascript. can i have to call these methods like URL.escape();

Comment: `escape` is deprecated. Do not use it.

Answer (score 8):

To be safe and ensure that you've escaped all the reserved characters specified in both RFC 1738 and RFC 3986 you should use a combination of encodeURIComponent, escape and a replace for the asterisk('*') like this:

```
encoded = encodeURIComponent( parm ).replace(/[!'()]/g, escape).replace(/\*/g, "%2A");
```

[Explanation]
While RFC 1738: Uniform Resource Locators (URL) specifies that the *, !, ', ( and ) characters may be left unencoded in the URL,

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>     reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>     unencoded within a URL.

RFC 3986, pages 12-13, states that these special characters are reserved as sub-delimiters.

> reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
> gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
> sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>                / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="

The escape() function has been deprecated but can be used to URL encode the exclamation mark, single quote, left parenthesis and right parenthesis.  And since there is some ambiguity on whether an asterisk must be encoded in a URL, and it doesn't hurt to encode, it you can explicitly encode is using something like the replace() function call.  [Note that the escape() function is being passed as the [second parameter to the first replace() function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114080/javascript-string-replace-with-regular-expression-and-function-as-arguments).  As used here, replace calls the escape() function once for each matched special character of !, ', ( or ), and escape merely returns the 'escape sequence' for that character back to replace, which reassembles any escaped characters with the other fragments.]

Also see ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533561/urlencode-the-asterisk-star-character'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533561/urlencode-the-asterisk-star-character)

Also while some websites have even identified the asterkisk(*) as being a reserved character under RFC3986, they don't include it in [their URL component encoding tool](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/).

Unencoded URL parms:

```
parm1=this is a test of encoding !@#$%^&*()'
parm2=note that * is not encoded
```

Encoded URL parms:

```
parm1=this+is+a+test+of+encoding+%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26*%28%29%27
parm2=note+that+*+is+not+encodeds+not+encoded
```