# Percent in url next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to create an url using:

```js
  const click = () => {
    router.push(
      {
        pathname:`/cars?{color}${doors}$`,
      },
      undefined,
      {
        shallow: true,
      },
  );
```

When i hit the button which trigger the function i get in url: `/cars%3Fcolor=red&doors=5`. 
How to create this url: `/cars?color=red&doors=5`,?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle % and # characters with next-routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54547227/how-to-handle-and-characters-with-next-routes)

Answer (score 4):

A `query` string cannot be part of a `pathname`. The `?` delimits the `query` string from the `pathname`; if a `pathname` were to *contain* a `?`, it would be encoded as `%3F`. This is why you're seeing this result.

Try this instead:

```js
router.push(
    {
        pathname: '/cars',
        query: { color, doors },
    },
    // ...
)
```

Comment: anyway in the url appears others signs that  shouldn't be there, like `%26`, i want to get something like this: `/cars?color=red&doors=5`, just simple signs not encoded url, do you know jow?

Comment: That's just the URL encoding of `&`, which is probably also due to not properly separating `pathname` from `query` string. Can you confirm if the solution I posted is failing?

Comment: yes it doesn't give the wanted result. Do you know an alternative?

Comment: could you help please with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410826/get-accesstoken-in-auth0. It will help a lot